Are there scams in linkedin job offers?
I received a few job offers through the Linkedin platform, these were on projects such as react and nodejs. A github repo is shared in the correspondence, short tasks are given and they want me to complete them. After a while, I realized that the accounts were closed.
Is it possible to share a file when NPM is debugged?
I did not send back any code, I just made developments or bug fixes on the projects and debugged them locally.
What do you think this is? What kind of fraud method?

So accounts that offered you a job were closed. Yes; They were scams.

They probably farmed those jobs out to multiple candidates and once they got sufficient work back just closed the account (obviously without paying anyone).

Or they simply found their candidate and are rudely assuming that if they stop responding you will simply continue to interview elsewhere. May bit be scam, but still makes me question whether you really want to work for that company. On the other other hand, they may just move through the hiring process very slowly. Continue interviewing elsewhere, and they will either get back to you or ghost you.

As the other answers already noted there can be scams on any social-media or professional platform. But I do want to mention a technical/security aspect:
Installing node.js and blindly cloning & running a repo from github raises a complete different issue other than doing free work for someone pretending to have a job-offer for you:
When you install Node.js, it typically inherits the permissions of the user who installs it. These permissions include but are not limited to:
File System:

Read and Write Permissions
Execution Permissions: Node.js can execute scripts and binaries. This includes running JavaScript files or native modules.
Inbound and Outbound Network Access
Environment Variables
Memory and CPU Usage
Process Control
IPC (Inter-Process Communication)
etc., etc.

I could continue the above list but I think you understand that running arbitrary, unknown sources can/might pose a large security risk. Anyone with an e-mail address can publish on github - so I would be very wary of untrusted sources in general.

There are in particular recently interview scams that try to infiltrate the machine of the interviewee. I.e. this is not hypothetical, but has been observed in the wild https://telefonicatech.com/en/blog/malware-job-interviews

@FrankHopkins thx for the info & link ;)

"Are there Scams on LinkedIn?"
Yes.
Investment Scams, Job Scams, Buzzword and Hype-train Scams.
Same with all forms of social media.

There have been job scams since people have been posting jobs on posts in the center of town.

I received a few job offers through the Linkedin platform, these were
on projects such as react and nodejs.

Social media has just changed the logistics of the scam.

A github repo is shared in the correspondence, short tasks are given
and they want me to complete them. After a while, I realized that the
accounts were closed.

Many a person has done hours of work, but then found the pay would never arrive. Or that the check would bounce. Or that it wasn't as much as had been promised.

yes, companies that have problems with doing short or small jobs or some fake organizations (such as individual companies) are tricking you into "do it and let's think about you".
